# Are there any real alternatives to unicode?

Tags: unicode

As a C++ developer supporting unicode is, putting it mildly, a pain in the butt. Unicode has a few unfortunate properties that makes it very hard to determine the case of a letter, convert them or pretty much anything beyond identifying a single known codepoint or so (which may or may not be a letter). The only real rescue, it seems, is [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) for those who are unfortunate enough to not have unicode support builtin the language (i.e. C and C++). Support for unicode in other languages may or may not be good enough.

So, I thought, there must be a *real* alternative to unicode! i.e. an encoding that does allow easy identification of character classes, besides having a lookup datastructure (tree, table, whatever), and identifying the relationship between characters? I suspect that any such encoding would likely be multi-byte for most text -- that's not a real concern to me, but I accept that it is for others. Providing such an encoding is a lot of work, so I'm not really expecting any such encoding to exist .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly is a pain; is it a C++-specific thing? Unicode defines a property category for each character, telling you if it's a letter or not, if it's upper or lower case or not cased at all, etc. It also provides tables that define upper-/lower-case correlations etc. Do find it cumbersome to *access* this information, or does it bother you things like uncased letters even exist?

Comment: I hadn't even considered uncased letters. It bothers me that I can't look at the character (a string of bytes) and just look at a few bits and know what set of class it shares with another string of bytes without having a lot of data. I explicitly have to check for each class for both characters. ASCII is probably the main reason for this problem. `i` for example; depending on the locale it can convert to all sorts of upper case characters, not just `I`.

Comment: You mix two things. The problem that the upper-case version of `i` is locale dependent has nothing to with Unicode or ASCII – you have to blame Kemal Atatürk for inventing `İ` a hundred years ago.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to be able to tell the category from the numeric codepoint, without tables. But it would be tricky to design such an encoding in an extensible way – as you might know, new characters are being added to Unicode every year.

Comment: @lenz Doesn't really change anything in this respect. An encoding (as cumbersome as it may be), could tell that `i` is a class and that `İ` is in the same class, but that `İ` is also in the upper case class, while `i` is in the lower case class (or default to not being in a cased class).

Comment: What do you mean by "an encoding could tell"? Unicode tells you exactly this, by means of the [PropList](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/PropList.txt).

Comment: I can't look at a string of bytes in utf-8 and just know what properties it has -- the properties are not encoded in the stream.

Comment: What's the point of another Unicode alternative? Then Unicode is not unique anymore and users would fly back to the time when there's a pain communicating worldwide. If you mean *encoding* then Unicode is not an encoding

Comment: Anyway I don't think there's any way to universally map a character to another one case, because each language has its own way to map characters casing, like the i example you've already seen. Moreover Unicode has a lot of flags in each codepoint [like this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0250/index.htm) and it's impossible to store them in a compact way. [Case mapping on Unicode is hard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030905-00/?p=42643)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I did mean encoding. There is a lot of pain *with* unicode because a lot of people do it wrong -- it's hard stuff to get right. I still haven't found a library that deals with unicode, that's not a pita to work with. ICU for example is pretty much just a poor attempt at wrapping a C library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: not that I know of.

As a non-C++ developer, I don't know what specifically is a pain about Unicode, but since you didn't tag the question with C++, I still dare to attempt an answer.

While I'm personally very happy about Unicode in general, I agree that some aspects are cumbersome.
Some of them could arguably be improved if Unicode was redesigned from scratch, eg. by removing some redundancies like the "Latin Greek" math letters besides the actual Greek ones (but that would also break compatibility with older encodings).

But most of the "pains" just reflect the chaotic usage of writing in the first place.
You mention yourself the problem of uppercase "i", which is "I" in some, "İ" in other orthographies, but there are tons of other difficulties – eg. German "ß", which is lowercase, but has no uppercase equivalent (well, it has now, but is rarely used); or letters that look different in final position (Greek "σ"/"ς"); or quotes with inverted meaning («French style» vs. »Swiss style«, “English” vs. „German style“)... I could continue for a while.

I don't see how an encoding could help with that, other than providing tables of character properties, equivalences, and relations, which is what Unicode does.
You say in comments that, by looking at the bytes of an encoded character, you want it to tell you if it's upper or lower case.
To me, this sounds like saying: "When I look at a number, I want it to tell me if it's prime."
I mean, not even ASCII codes tell you if they are upper or lower case, you just memorised the properties table which tells you that `41..5A` is upper, `61..7A` is lower case.
But it's hard to memorise or hardcode these ranges for all 120k Unicode codepoints. So the easiest thing is to use a table look-up.

There's also a bit of confusion about what "encoding" means.
Unicode doesn't define any byte representation, it only assigns codepoints, ie. integers, to character definitions, and it maintains the said tables.
Encodings in the strict sense ("codecs") are the *transformation formats* (UTF-8 etc.), which define a mapping between the codepoints and their byte representation.
Now it would be possible to define a new UTF which maps codepoints to bytes in a way that provides a pattern for upper/lower case.
But what could that be?
Odd for upper, even for lower case?
But what about letters without upper-/lower-case distinction?
And then, characters that aren't letters?
And what about all the other character categories – punctuation, digits, whitespace, symbols, combining diacritics –, why not represent those as well?
You could put each in a predefined range, but what happens if too many new characters are added to one of the categories?

To sum it up: I don't think what you ask for is possible.

Comment: Having letters that have no case, only lower case or only upper case isn't really a problem -- as long as you can identify that one letter is equivalent to another if you don't take case into account that's fine. The real problem seems to be that some cultures define the rules for how to convert between cases to be different. I.e. ê compares equal to E in some language but not in others. It's *very* easy to tell if an ASCII character is upper or lower case. ß does have a single letter uppercase equivalent. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e9e/index.htm

Comment: The graphical representation is not important in the context of searching.

Comment: You keep bringing up new stuff – who said anything about graphical representation? You talk about collation now (equivalences between characters), which is certainly a cumbersome topic, but how would a new encoding help here? You give the examples yourself – they all reflect inconsistent lexicographic rules. And of course it's a pain if other people get Unicode wrong, but, seriously, how would *yet another* encoding be of help?

Comment: You brought up graphical representation. I'm pointing out that it's irrelevant. If the graphical representation changes because of context, is irrelevant to determine what classes of letters it belongs to.

Comment: I don't think I did, but maybe we're not talking about the same stuff. I was probably thinking about choice of glyphs, a topic which is certainly irrelevant here and which I didn't touch (the sigma example is not about glyphs: σ and ς are different code points, but they have the same uppercase counterpart).

Comment: Downvote because this explains your opinion but does not present an alternative. Alternatives do exist. If you illustrate at least one and compare the viability I would unvote.

Comment: @ThatRealtyProgrammerGuy This sounds like the perfect opportunity for you to present these alternatives in a new answer in this thread! 

Comment: @lenz mmm I could but it doesn't seem as good of an option since you have a quality answer already. But for example: ISO 10646, KOI8-R, ISO 6937, T.61, Braille (digitized), Morse code (digitized)

Comment: ASCII was specifically designed so that upper- and lower-case letters were distinguished by a single bit. You'll notice that the character values are 0x20 apart.

Comment: I know – it's an elegant solution for a (comparatively) simple problem. Unicode is all about solving a very hard problem. What exactly is your point, @aghast?

Comment: Besides, the 0x20 distance between lower and upper case letters is present in many subsections of Unicode. But it's impossible to perfectly do this if the writing systems don't have 1:1 mappings.

Comment: My point is that you can't say things like *"I mean, not even ASCII codes tell you if they are upper or lower case,"* and expect to get away with it. ;-)

Comment: I stand by that. The number 65 (hex 41) doesn't by itself bear the meaning of being upper case – it's just a reference to some table of properties. If that table is small and has some inner logic, you may get tempted to think you can solve text-processing problems through arithmetics. But it just doesn't scale when you start working with more characters than what fits on a 1950 typewriter.